# Angular-tablesort breaks

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

`angular-tablesort` is saving me a lot of time, but i'm hitting a bug where I can't get the header to become sortable even though I am following the examples and adding the classes. My code looks like this:

```
<table class="table" ts-wrapper>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="tablesort-sortable" ts-criteria="Name|lowercase" ts-default>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items" ts-repeat>
      <td>{{item.data.title}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved!

As I was working through how best to present this to you guys I realized that this was an RTFM problem. I was confused by the fact that the example matches the `ts-criteria` with the div contents and didn't match the `ng-repeat` contents fully. `angular-table` actually lets you pass in `item.data.title` or `data.title` to get a sortable table.

A little embarrassing, but I'm still going to post this in case someone else comes across the same issue. This has nothing to do with bootstrapped angular applications, which was my first hunch. Changed the title to be more generic (from *Angular-tablesort breaks when angular is bootstrapped* to *Angular-tablesort breaks*).